# Could I execute smach in c++?

Tags: python, c++, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've made a state machine, but I need to compile it into c++, because I need to execute in the Nao.

Is there a way to execute Smach in Nao using python?.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42978/could-i-execute-smach-in-c++?/) by [Wladimir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3137/wladimir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) on 2012-09-05**:
Have you looked into http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/python/index.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Loy's answer to just run Python on the NAO looks like the right solution. SMACH is a pure python library. Though there have been implementations of SMACH semantics in other languages, there is no native implementation that I know of in c/c++.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1